# Calculate Rademacher complexity of linear regression

Tags: machine-learning, linear-model

Given $$\mathcal{F} = \{f(x) = W^{T}x, \|W\|_{2} \leq w\}$$ I am interested in determining the Rademacher complexity of $\mathcal{F}$. How would one start this computation?

Comment: Begin by [specifying the underlying probability distribution.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rademacher_complexity)

Comment: My first step is to write down the formal Rademacher complexity: $$\mathbb{E} \sup_{W, \|W\|_{2} \leq w} \Big| \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n} \sigma_{i}W^{T}x_{i} \Big|$$ with the Rademacher random variable $\sigma_{i}$. Is this the right step?

Comment: Do you want the exact value or upper/lower bounds ?

Comment: I am not very sure. Since this is essentially the Rademacher complexity of linear models, would determining an exact value be possible?

Comment: I'm not aware of an exact expression for the Rademacher complexity of linear hypothesis class, but it is fairly straightforward to obtain upper (and lower) bounds for it. Use the classical inequalities like Jensen and Cauchy-Schwarz and you should get something (assuming the domain of the $x_i$ is bounded).

Comment: Any chance I can get a starting point for this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finding an upper bound on $\mathfrak R (\mathcal F)$ is fairly straightforward. Assuming there is an upper bound $B$ such that $\Vert x\Vert_2 \le B $ for all $x$ in the domain, we have :
$$\begin{align}\mathfrak R (\mathcal F) &:=\mathbb{E}\left[ \sup_{W, \|W\|_{2} \leq w} \Big| \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n} \sigma_{i}W^{T}x_{i} \Big|\right]\\
&=\frac{1}{n}\mathbb{E}\left[ \sup_{W, \|W\|_{2} \leq w} \Big|  W^{T}\sum_{i=1}^{n} \sigma_{i}x_{i} \Big|\right]\\
&\le \frac{1}{n}\mathbb{E}\left[ \sup_{W, \|W\|_{2} \leq w} \Vert  W\Vert_2 \left\lVert\sum_{i=1}^{n} \sigma_{i}x_{i} \right\rVert_2\right] \,\text{(Cauchy-Schwarz)}\\
&=\frac{1}{n}\mathbb{E}\left[ w \left\lVert\sum_{i=1}^{n} \sigma_{i}x_{i} \right\rVert_2\right]\\
&=\frac{w}{n}\mathbb{E}\left[  \sqrt{\left\langle\sum_{i=1}^{n} \sigma_{i}x_{i} ,\sum_{i=1}^{n} \sigma_{i}x_{i} \right\rangle}\right]\\
&=\frac{w}{n}\mathbb{E}\left[  \sqrt{\sum_{1\le i,j\le n} \sigma_{i}\sigma_{j}\langle x_{i} ,x_{j} \rangle}\right]\\
&\le \frac{w}{n}  \sqrt{\mathbb{E}\left[\sum_{1\le i,j\le n} \sigma_{i}\sigma_{j}\langle x_{i} ,x_{j} \rangle\right]}\,\text{(Jensen)}\\
&=\frac{w}{n}  \sqrt{\sum_{1\le i,j\le n} \mathbb{E}\left[\sigma_{i}\sigma_{j}\right]\langle x_{i} ,x_{j} \rangle}\\
&=\frac{ w}{n}  \sqrt{\sum_{1\le i\le n} \Vert x_{i} \Vert_2^2}\\
&\le \frac{wB}{\sqrt n}
\end{align} $$
Although this upper bound is obtained by fairly elementary techniques, it is quite good in the sense that it matches the lower bound up to a constant factor. To obtain the expression of the lower bound, you can proceed similarly and use Khitchine's inequality. The details of the computation and a more general discussion is available in this paper by Awasthi, Frank and Mohri: [On the Rademacher Complexity of Linear Hypothesis Sets (2020)](https://arxiv.org/abs/2007.11045).